# Is there a root Elixir module?

Tags: elixir

When I define a module in Elixir and perform a `to_string` operation on it like this in IEX

`MyModule |> to_string`

I will get the result,

`"Elixir.MyModule"`

Is there a root level `Elixir` module that all other modules live in? Why is there an Elixir prefix that looks like another module?

[This website](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#alias) says it is a namespace but I have read other articles that say Elixir does not support namespaces.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ Elixir does surely support namespaces (well, if we are using the common meaning of “namespaces”.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "Programming Elixir 1.6" Dave Thomas gives this example:

`defmodule​ Outer ​do​
​  ​defmodule​ Inner ​do​
​​      def​ inner_func ​do​
​​      end​
​​  end​
​ 
​​  def​ outer_func ​do​
    ​Inner.inner_func
​​  end​
​​end​
​
​Outer.outer_func
​Outer.Inner.inner_func`

He then explains:

"Module nesting in Elixir is an illusion—all modules are defined at the top level. When we define a module inside another, Elixir simply prepends the outer module name to the inner module name, putting a dot between the two. This means we can directly define a nested module."

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is for make a difference between Elixir and Erlang modules. All elixir modules are starting with `Elixir` prefix.
`MyModule` is just an alias for an atom `:"Elixir.MyModule"`:

```
iex(1)> defmodule MyModule, do: def f(), do: "MyModule.f()"
```

Standard function call:

```
iex(2)> MyModule.f()
"MyModule.f()"
```

Erlang-style function call:

```
iex(3)> :"Elixir.MyModule".f()
"MyModule.f()"
```

Is the atom equal to alias?

```
iex(4)> :"Elixir.MyModule" == MyModule
true
iex(5)> :"Elixir.MyModule" == Elixir.MyModule
true
```

`Elixir` prefix is for convenience:

```
iex(6)> MyModule == Elixir.MyModule
true
```